# How to clip the bounds of scrollview in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, android-scrollview

I have an image view inside of a linear layout inside of a scrollview.  I cannot get the ScrollView to stop scrolling both above and below the image.  I do not want the user to be able to scroll past the bounds of the image.
Here is my XML:

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewLegend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@color/Copper"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/legend"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an option, setting the layout height of the ImageView to a fixed value will resolve this issue.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:src="@drawable/legend"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"/>
```